# List is broken and not adding

Tags: java

The code is originally written by @Arvind.
I give credit.
I will just use I as a noun.

I have four classes, Item, Store, Customer, Online.

Whenever I found an item in Online class,

I want to added via addingitem() from Store class.

I am using Link so I can store, delete multiple items.

But the things is that when I try to store it.

I work perfectly with debug to itemLists.add();

but when trying to look what is in the itemLists with debugger,
the size is zero and nothing is in there.

I don't know why.

I need a temporary list or something else to store multiple strings. 
I am using list because it can be added, deleted and printed.

Let say if I add this item, because it exists.

`001A:GTA`.

Ok, I will added another item ,

`001C:The last of us`

it should not only store that but when I want to view that what I have stored. The result should be.

```
001A:GTA
001C:The last of us
```

Can someone explain to me?
Thanks.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Objects;

    class Item {
        private String code, name;

        public Item(String code, String name) {
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public String getNumber(){
                return number;
       }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + " : " + code;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name, code);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Item item = (Item) obj;
            return name.equals(item.name) && code.equals(item.code);
        }
    }

    class Store {
        private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
        private String name, number;

        public Store(String name, String number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void addItem(String code, String name) {
            items.add(new Item(code, name));
        }

        public LinkedList<Item> findItems() {
            return items;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Item item : items) {
                sb.append(item.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

    public List<String> addingitem(Item item){
            List<String> itemLists = new ArrayList<>();
            itemsList.add(item.getName() + item.geNumber() + “ added”);
            return null;
        }

        public void viewStore() {
            System.out.println(name + " " + number);
        }

        /**
         * Searches the item in the store using the search string
         * 
         * @param The string combining the code and name in the format "code:name:"
         * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
         */
        public Item findItem(String strItem) {
            String[] data = strItem.split(":");
            if (data.length < 2) {
                return null;
            }

            Item searchItem = new Item(data[0], data[1]);

            for (Item item : items) {
                if (item.equals(searchItem)) {
                    return item;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Searches the item in the store using the name of the item
         * 
         * @param The name of the item
         * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
         */
        public Item findItemByName(String itemName) {
            for (Item item : items) {
                if (item.getName().equals(itemName)) {
                    return item;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class Customer {
        private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();

        public Customer() {
            stores.add(new Store("Game", "1"));
            stores.add(new Store("Grocery", "2"));

            stores.get(0).addItem("001A", "GTA");
            stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
            stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

            stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
            stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
            stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
        }

        public LinkedList<Store> getStores() {
            return stores;
        }

        public void viewStore() {
            for (Store store : stores)
                store.viewStore();
        }

        public void viewItems() {
            for (Store store : stores) {
                for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                    System.out.println(item);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Searches the item in all the stores related to the customer using the search
         * string
         * 
         * @param The string combining the code and name in the format "code:name:"
         * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
         */
        public Item findItem(String strItem) {
            String[] data = strItem.split(":");
            if (data.length < 2) {
                return null;
            }

            Item searchItem = new Item(data[0], data[1]);

            for (Store store : stores) {
                for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                    if (item.equals(searchItem)) {
                        return item;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Searches the item in all the stores related to the customer using the name of
         * the item
         * 
         * @param The name of the item
         * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
         */
        public Item findItemByName(String itemName) {
            for (Store store : stores) {
                for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                    if (item.getName().equals(itemName)) {
                        return item;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Online {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Item item;
            String strItem, itemName;
            Customer customer = new Customer();

            // Test searching the item using the search string in a particular store e.g.
            // first store of customer
            Store store = customer.getStores().get(0);
            System.out.println("Searching item using search string in store, " + store.getName());

            strItem = "001A:GTA";
            item = store.findItem(strItem);
            if (item == null) {
                System.out.println("Not found -> " + strItem);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
                        store.addingItem(item);
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment, you've posted over 200 lines of code. While it's great to provide a complete example, I strongly suspect that's much more code than you actually need to demonstrate the problem. For example, are `findItem` and `findItemByName` actually necessary in order to show that the list is empty? Remove everything that's not necessary to demonstrate the problem - and I suspect you'll find the bug as you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. Because of `List<String> itemLists = new ArrayList<>();`, the `itemLists` is getting reset every time you are calling the method, `addingitem`.
2. Despite the mistake mentioned the point#1 (given above), you would have got a list of size, `1` had you returned the `itemLists` after adding item to it. However, you have returned `null` nullifying whatever you've done with `itemLists`.
3. In the class, `Online`, you are trying to find an item and if it is found, you are trying to add it again by calling `store.addingItem`. This logic doesn't seem right. It should be the other way round i.e. if the item doesn't exist in store, it should be added to it.
4. If you are trying to add all the found items to a list in the class, `Online`, you need a `List` in the class, `Online`. You can simply add the found items to this list and print the list whenever you need to do so.

The following code incorporates all these points:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

class Item {
    private String code, name;

    public Item(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + code;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, code);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Item item = (Item) obj;
        return name.equals(item.name) && code.equals(item.code);
    }
}

class Store {
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
    private String name, number;

    public Store(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void addItem(String code, String name) {
        items.add(new Item(code, name));
    }

    public void addItem(String strItem) {
        String[] data = strItem.split(":");
        if (data.length < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item string must be in the format code:name");
        }
        items.add(new Item(data[0], data[1]));
    }

    public LinkedList<Item> findItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Item item : items) {
            sb.append(item.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void viewStore() {
        System.out.println(name + " " + number);
    }

    /**
     * Searches the item in the store using the search string
     * 
     * @param The string combining the code and name in the format "code:name:"
     * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
     */
    public Item findItem(String strItem) {
        String[] data = strItem.split(":");
        if (data.length < 2) {
            return null;
        }

        Item searchItem = new Item(data[0], data[1]);

        for (Item item : items) {
            if (item.equals(searchItem)) {
                return item;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Searches the item in the store using the name of the item
     * 
     * @param The name of the item
     * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
     */
    public Item findItemByName(String itemName) {
        for (Item item : items) {
            if (item.getName().equals(itemName)) {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Customer {
    private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();

    public Customer() {
        stores.add(new Store("Game", "1"));
        stores.add(new Store("Grocery", "2"));

        stores.get(0).addItem("001A", "GTA");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

        stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
    }

    public LinkedList<Store> getStores() {
        return stores;
    }

    public void viewStore() {
        for (Store store : stores)
            store.viewStore();
    }

    public void viewItems() {
        for (Store store : stores) {
            for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Searches the item in all the stores related to the customer using the search
     * string
     * 
     * @param The string combining the code and name in the format "code:name:"
     * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
     */
    public Item findItem(String strItem) {
        String[] data = strItem.split(":");
        if (data.length < 2) {
            return null;
        }

        Item searchItem = new Item(data[0], data[1]);

        for (Store store : stores) {
            for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                if (item.equals(searchItem)) {
                    return item;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Searches the item in all the stores related to the customer using the name of
     * the item
     * 
     * @param The name of the item
     * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
     */
    public Item findItemByName(String itemName) {
        for (Store store : stores) {
            for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                if (item.getName().equals(itemName)) {
                    return item;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Online {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item item;
        String strItem, itemName;
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        // List to hold the items which are found
        List<Item> itemsList = new LinkedList<Item>();

        // Test searching the item using the search string in a particular store e.g.
        // first store of customer
        Store store = customer.getStores().get(0);
        System.out.println("Searching item using search string in store, " + store.getName());

        strItem = "001A:GTA";
        item = store.findItem(strItem);
        if (item != null) {
            itemsList.add(item);
        } else {
            System.out.println("'" + strItem + "'" + " was not found in in store, " + store.getName());
        }

        strItem = "001D:The Wizarding World of Harry Potter";
        item = store.findItem(strItem);
        if (item != null) {
            itemsList.add(item);
        } else {
            System.out.println("'" + strItem + "'" + " was not found in in store, " + store.getName());
        }

        strItem = "001B:GOD OF WARS";
        item = store.findItem(strItem);
        if (item != null) {
            itemsList.add(item);
        } else {
            System.out.println("'" + strItem + "'" + " was not found in in store, " + store.getName());
        }

        strItem = "ABC:XYZ";
        item = store.findItem(strItem);
        if (item != null) {
            itemsList.add(item);
        } else {
            System.out.println("'" + strItem + "'" + " was not found in in store, " + store.getName());
        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Items which have been found:");
        itemsList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println();

        // Test adding "ABC:XYZ" to store, Game
        strItem = "ABC:XYZ";
        try {
            store.addItem(strItem);
            System.out.println("Item, '" + strItem + "' has been added to the store successfully.");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        // Test finding the newly added item to the store
        strItem = "ABC:XYZ";
        item = store.findItem(strItem);
        if (item != null) {
            itemsList.add(item);
        } else {
            System.out.println("'" + strItem + "'" + " was not found in in store, " + store.getName());
        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Updated list of items which have been found:");
        itemsList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Searching item using search string in store, Game
'001D:The Wizarding World of Harry Potter' was not found in in store, Game
'ABC:XYZ' was not found in in store, Game

Items which have been found:
GTA : 001A
GOD OF WARS : 001B

Item, 'ABC:XYZ' has been added to the store successfully.

Updated list of items which have been found:
GTA : 001A
GOD OF WARS : 001B
XYZ : ABC
```

**Side notes (because these changes won't affect the execution in any way):**

1. Follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the method, `addingitem` should renamed as `addingItem`.
2. You have used the name, `itemLists` for a variable which is supposed be list of strings, not a list of lists and therefore it should be named as `itemList` to avoid confusion. Remember, the name of an identifier should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Good Morning @Arvind. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Good Morning!  You are most welcome.

Comment: So, there's no way to store temporary data list.

Comment: I want a temporary place to store data if I store items.add(), I cannot check the only items that I add. It display all the items that I have added in Store class.

Comment: @ratRedTears - Why not? I've updated the answer to incorporate it.

Comment: My false that I should have put more details. I am very sorry.

Comment: No worries. Just go through and test the updated code. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212554/discussion-between-ratredtears-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).

Comment: I think I am not allow to add new List except for LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();

Comment: That's fine. You can use that way. However, sooner or later you will have to start using it the way, I have used it. Probably, your professor will ask all of you to start using it in my way after he/she will teach you all [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Comment: I think your way is better. There're too much restrictions, I don't feel like programming anymore.

Comment: Ah...don't lose heart...these are initial hiccups...you will enjoy programming as you will learn and practice more. I wish you success!

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods `addItem` (which looks correct, as it adds items to the member field) and another one `addingItem` which always creates a new, empty, *local* list before adding the item. (on second thought: your method-local variable is called `itemLists`, but the list to which the item is added is called `itemsList`). When calling `addingItem` your list – which is a variable local to the method – will only contain that single item.

Since you are returning `null` from that method which, this method-local list variable will be garbage collected once the method has finished executing.

Suggestion: use clear names and avoid confusing, too-similar names (`addItem` vs `addingItem`, `itemsList` vs `itemLists`). It makes it far too easy to use the wrong variable/method (as perfectly illustrated by your "bug")

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that `addingitem` is very odd, since it creates a new list, adds 1 item to it and then does nothing with it, i think the issue in that function is that you instantiate a variable called `itemLists` and add the new item to another variable called `itemsList`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public List<String> addingitem(Item item){
>     List<String> itemLists = new ArrayList<>();
>     itemsList.add(item.getName() + item.geNumber() + “ added”);
>     return null;
> }
> ```

This code of yours doesn't do anything useful. It creates a new (temporary) list `itemLists` and add one string to it. After that nothing happens and you do nothing with the `itemLists` variable. You even always return the value `null` from the method. This method could be replaced by

```
 public List<String> addingitem(Item item){
     return null;
 }
```

and it would be the same code. This also shows, why there is no item saved, because you do exactly that, not saving anything.

Depending on what you want to do you, you have to work with the `this.items` list and add new items to that list. So the code have to look something like this:

```
 public List<String> addingitem(Item item){
     this.items.add(item); // add the given item to the list of items of the store.
     return null;
 }
```

It is unknown what the return value should be so I keep it being `null`, but you might replace it for what you want to do there.

Comment: how can I create temporary list and add multiple strings.

Comment: Just like you did with your code, but you have to do something with your `itemLists` variable. Also, keep in mind that with your code, you always create a fresh empty list and add one string to it. It does not use the `this.items` list as it possible should, depending on what this method should do.

Comment: aww ok. So, there's no ways except using this. But Thanks you very much for advice.